# How does storage space (Simple), without resilience, save the files on the harddisk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-failure, storage-spaces

If you create for example 3x4tb Storage spaces, without any resilience (simple), and one drive crashes, **will you lose everything, or just that's on just that drive?**

is it saving the data in stripes over all disks?

Is the system filling up drive 1, then drive 2 or how is it working?

Comment: From reading in it you loose everything. Depending his its configured it behaves similarly to jbod or RAID0. You should not use it as reliable storage. If you keep a tight ship with defragmentation and select the mode which performs like jbid rather then striping you may have some (very limited but better then using striping) success using data recovery - but really, don't use it for data you care about unless you have strong backups.

Comment: @davidgo thx, I've got external backup (usb) but that's soooo slow, but it will work..